# Why does Eunit not require test functions to be exported?

Tags: erlang, eunit

I'm going through the EUnit chapter in [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/eunit#the-need-for-tests) and one thing I am noticing from all the code samples is the test functions are never declared in `-export()` clauses.

Why is EUnit able to pick these test functions up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html):

> The simplest way to use EUnit in an Erlang module is to add the following line at the beginning of the module (after the `-module` declaration, but before any function definitions):
>
> ```
> -include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
> ```
>
> This will have the following effect:
>
> - **Creates an exported function** `test()` (unless testing is turned off, and the module does not already contain a test() function), that can be used to run all the unit tests defined in the module
> - **Causes all functions whose names match** `..._test()` or `..._test_()` **to be automatically exported from the module** (unless testing is turned off, or the `EUNIT_NOAUTO` macro is defined)

Answer (score 0):

Glad I found this question because it gives me a meaningful way to procrastinate and I was wondering how functions get created and exported dynamically.

Started by looking at the latest commit affecting EUnit in the Erlang/OTP Github repo, which is [4273cbd](https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05). (The only reason for this was to find a relatively stable anchor instead of git branches.)

## 0. Include EUnit's header file

According [EUnit's User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html), the first step is to `-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").` in the tested module, so I assume this is where the magic happens.

## 1. [`otp/lib/eunit/include/eunit.hrl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05/lib/eunit/include/eunit.hrl) (lines 79 - 91)

```
%% Parse transforms for automatic exporting/stripping of test functions.
%% (Note that although automatic stripping is convenient, it will make
%% the code dependent on this header file and the eunit_striptests
%% module for compilation, even when testing is switched off! Using
%% -ifdef(EUNIT) around all test code makes the program more portable.)

-ifndef(EUNIT_NOAUTO).
-ifndef(NOTEST).
-compile({parse_transform, eunit_autoexport}).
-else.
-compile({parse_transform, eunit_striptests}).
-endif.
-endif.
```

### 1.1 What does `-compile({parse_transform, eunit_autoexport}).` mean?

From the Erlang Reference Manual's Module chapter ([Pre-Defined Module Attributes](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html#pre-defined-module-attributes)):

> `-compile(Options).`
>    Compiler options. Options is a single option or a list of options. This attribute is added to the option list when
>   compiling the module. See the **[compile(3)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html)** manual page in Compiler.

On to [compile(3)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html):

> `{parse_transform,Module}`
>    Causes the parse transformation function
>   Module:parse_transform/2 to be applied to the parsed code before the
>   code is checked for errors.

From the [`erl_id_trans`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_id_trans.html) module:

> This module performs an identity parse transformation of Erlang code.
>   It is included as an example for users who wants to write their own
>   parse transformers. If option `{parse_transform,Module}` is passed to
>   the compiler, a user-written function `parse_transform/2` is called by
>   the compiler before the code is checked for errors.

Basically, if module M includes the `{parse_transform, Module}` compile option, then all of M's functions and attributes can be iterated through using your implementation of `Module:parse_transform/2`. Its first argument is `Forms`, which is M's module declaration described in Erlang's [**abstract format**](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/absform.html) (described in [Erlang Run-Time System Application (ERTS) User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/users_guide.html).

## 2. [`otp/lib/eunit/src/eunit_autoexport.erl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05/lib/eunit/src/eunit_autoexport.erl)

This module only exports `parse_transfrom/2` to satisfy `{parse_transform, Module}` compile option and its first order of business is to figure out what are the configured suffixes for test case functions and generators. If not set manually, using `_test` and `_test_` respectively (via [`lib/eunit/src/eunit_internal.hrl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05/lib/eunit/src/eunit_internal.hrl)).

It then scans all the functions and attributes of your module using [`eunit_autoexport:form/5`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05/lib/eunit/src/eunit_autoexport.erl#L49), and builds a list of to be exported functions where the suffixes above match (plus the original functions. I may be wrong on this one...).

Finally, [`eunit_autoexport:rewrite/2`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05/lib/eunit/src/eunit_autoexport.erl#L73) builds a module declaration from the original `Forms` (given to [`eunit_autoexport:parse_transform/2`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05/lib/eunit/src/eunit_autoexport.erl#L34) as the first argument) and the list of functions to be exported (that was supplied by `form/5` above). On [line 82](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/4273cbd12075265853bb4791fb74c11032b9be05/lib/eunit/src/eunit_autoexport.erl#L82) it injects the `test/0` function mentioned in the [EUnit documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#including-the-eunit-header-file).